# vlc hardware encoding for real-time screen multicast

Tags: encoding, hardware, multicast, vlc

We are preparing a solution to multicast the teacher's screen to 40 students' pcs.
Teacher and students pcs can be both Ubuntu and Windows.

Some solutions were tested :

- iTalc ... not stable yet.
- multicast a "vnc -viewonly" ... no solution found
- capture the screen with VLC and multicast it.

That latest seems to work ... except that with a resolution like 1920x1200 it is just too much CPU intensive.

One idea would be to capture only the 4th of the screen. CPU is not saturated anymore but everything becomes really slow and the surface is too small anyway.

A second idea is to buy a PCI card (or something) which will be dedicated to real-time video encoding.

Anyone has an experience/knowledge on it?

Thanks!

Comment: 1920x1200 realtime is incredibly memory and processor intensive, consider not many machines can decode HDTV videos in realtime without hardware acceleration.  Also, encoding is more demanding than decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the TightVNC project's [TightProjector](http://www.tightvnc.com/projector/).

> TightProjector is a program that can transmit the screen of a
>   particular Windows computer to other computers in the same local-area
>   network. The data is transmitted continuously, in real time.

Comment: Thanks. We were skeptic about the performances doing VNC without multicast for so many clients. In fact, in our largest room (40 PC) ThightVNC did it pretty well with really better performance than doing video encoding. We'll work this way next semester.

Comment: @samb Also realise VNC implementations are always improving, [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.sourceforge.net/) for example just released a higher performance version that should scale further on basic TCP connections.